# how to accessing/Updating a map in some header file from another file/class

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

I have a few classes and would like to access/update a map in one of the classes.
I am a novice to c++ and am having a hard time to figure out how to achieve this...
Basically, it's adding the work (here it's just a string, but it's actually like I am creating an object using the data from the string (like tokenizing) and need to save that object as a key into the frame map as a value.

paint_service.h

```
namespace Hello {
namespace World {

class PaintService {
    public:
        PaintService();
        void start_painting(...);
    private:
        **map<string, string> d_frames;**
}; }}
```

paint_service.cpp

```
namespace Hello {
namespace World {
PaintService::PaintService() { }
void PaintService::start_painting(...) {
    PaintDistributer paint_distributer;
    //works = ... assuming there's this works is like vector of string
    for(String work: works) {
        paint_distributer.distribute(work);
    }
}
}}
```

paint_distributer.cpp

```
namespace Hello {
namespace World { 
...
Event PaintDistributer::distribute(const string& work) {
   string work_type = work.substring(3,5);
   if (work_type == "framing") {
        **// I wanna add this "work" to the map, d_frames in PaintService, how can I do this?**
        return Event(something(work))
   }
} }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what you are returning is not what you want inserted?

Comment: @Surt yes, i'm returning something else that's a type Event, which is not included here. That adding to a map is just a part of logic I would like to get handled before returning.

Comment: So PaintDistributer constructed in PaintService must take a reference to PaintService so that you can add to the map there.

Comment: `string work_type = work.substring(3,5);` will return a string of at most 5 characters so it will never be equal to `"framing"`. I would also recommend writing `namespace Hello::World {` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (untested code).

In `PaintService` add

```
void Add(string key, string value) {
  d_frames[key] = value;
}
```

In the call to `start_painting` add a reference to the owning instance.

```
PaintDistributer paint_distributer(*this); // constructor needs a reference owner
```

And in distribute add

```
if (work_type == "framing") {
  owner.Add("distributor", work_type); // or what you want to register.
}
```